# Which of these functions is more testable in C?

Tags: c, unit-testing, testing, tdd

I write code in C. I have been striving to write more testable code but I am a little
confused on deciding between writing pure functions that are really good for testing
but require smaller functions and hurt readability in my opinion and writing functions
that do modify some internal state.

For example (all state variables are declared static and hence are "private" to my module):

Which of this is more testable in your opinion:

```
int outer_API_bar()
{
   // Modify internal state
   internal_foo()
}

int internal_foo()
{
  // Do stuff

  if (internal_state_variable)
  {
     // Do some more stuff
     internal_state_variable = false;
  }
}
```

OR

```
int outer_API_bar()
{
   // Modify internal state

   internal_foo(internal_state_variable)

   // This could be another function if repeated many
   // times in the module
   if (internal_state_variable)
   {
      internal_state_variable = false;
   }
}

int internal_foo(bool arg)
{
  // Do stuff

  if (arg)
  {
     // Do some more stuff
  }
}
```

Although second implementation is more testable wrt to internal_foo as it has no sideeffects but it makes bar uglier and requires smaller functions that make it hard for the reader to even follow small snippets as he has to constantly shift attention to different functions.

Which one do you think is better ? Compare this to writing OOPS code, the private functions most of the time use internal state and are not pure. Testing is done by setting up internal state on a mock object instance and testing the private function. I am getting a little confused on whether to use or whether to pass in internal state to private functions for the sake of "testability"

Comment: It is more a matter of readability than of testability.

Comment: What does this question have to do with `Java`?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch still I would want test coverage for internal_foo(), won't it be better if I can test with internal_foo(true) , internal_foo(false), rather than set state = true; internal_foo()

Comment: It depends upon your testing framework or habits. It is a matter of opinion.

Comment: I wonder whether there is any helpful discussion on testability vs. encapsulation in C? For example, I have seen code that encapsulates `internal_state_variable` inside `internal_foo()`, which makes it even harder to test (this will circumvent any testing that relies on redefining STATIC for test purposes). Why is it that we often can't find the "impact on the wider application", as @robjohncox pointed out below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever writing automated tests, ideally we want to focus on testing the specification of that unit of code, not the implementation (otherwise we create fragile tests that will break whenever we modify the implementation). Therefore, what happens internally in the object should not be of concern to the test.

For this example, I would look to build a test that:

- Executes the test by calling `outer_API_bar`.
- Asserts that the correct behavior of the call using other publicly accessible functions and/or state (there must be some way of doing this, as if the only side effect of calling `outer_API_bar` was internal to this unit of code, then calling this function could not impact your wider application in any way, and essentially be useless).

This way, you are able to keep the fact that you use functions like `internal_foo`, and variables like `internal_state_variable` as implementation details, which you can freely change when refactoring your code (i.e. to make it more readable) without having to change your tests.

**NOTE:** This suggestion is based on my own personal preference for only testing public functions, and not private ones. You will find much debate on this topic where some people pose good arguments for testing private functions being a valid thing to do.

Comment: "there must be some way of doing this, as if the only side effect of calling outer_API_bar was internal to this unit of code, then calling this function could not impact your wider application in any way, and essentially be useless". Interesting point. Makes me wonder why I have encountered so much code where it _seems_ practically impossible to reach every possible state of every internal function via the external API. In my experience, these states do impact the wider application in some way. Or do they really? What is wrong in this picture? How can this code be improved?

Comment: That's a really good question, I've felt the same and don't have a good answer. It may be simply a result of procedural code being harder to test than OO code (OO is my background, and I suspect the background of most people who've done lots of automated testing). When you have an object to work with you have a unit to test that is easy to build discrete test steps around (do this, then assert this state), whereas testing procedural code you lose the state of the unit under test after you call the function you are testing, and rely on asserting side effects or return values only.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question very specifically pure functions are waaaaay more 'testable' than any other kind of abstraction. The more pure functions you can include, the more testable your code would be.  As you rightly mention, this can come at the cost of readability, and I am sure there are other trade offs to consider. My suggestion would be to aim for more pure functions and look for other techniques that would allow you to compensate on the readability side of things.

Answer (score 0):

Both snippets are testable via mocks. The second one, however, has the advantage that you can also check the argument of `internal_foo(bool arg)` for an expected value of `true` or `false` when the mock for `internal_foo()` is invoked. In my opinion, that would make for a more meaningful test.

Depending on the rest of the code that we don't know, testing without mocks may be more difficult.

Comment: I just realized my answer is wrong. You cannot mock an internal function. Mocks can only test where an external API is called.